# Using PRXPARSE and PRXSUBSTR to extract pieces of a string

Tags: sas

Using SAS 9.3 I want to extract the portion of each string between the "." (dot) and '"' (double quote) that follows the dot.  For example the result of line one below should be f2015_cnt_cont_line

```
      <characteristic abc="[2015].f2015_cnt_cont_line" xxxxxxxx="8129" />
      <characteristic abc="[2015].f2015_dbt_cont_line" xxxxxxxx="8134" />
      <characteristic abc="[2015].f2015_ctl_tot_acct_bal" xxxxxxxx="8133" />
      <characteristic abc="[2015].f2015_cnt_comb_line" xxxxxxxx="8118" />
      <characteristic abc="[2015].f2015_dbt_comb_line" xxxxxxxx="8138" />
```

Does anyone have an example I could use?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
inner = SCAN(SUBSTR(line,INDEX(line,'.')+1),1,'"');
```

The inner SUBSTR function skips to the column after the first dot; the outer SCAN function returns the first word delimited by a double quote.

Comment: Interesting approach.  Works great. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

A regular expression that matches your pattern is `\.(.*?)\"`. This means: find a dot (a special character; then any character (the ? makes it not "greedy", so it captures as few characters as possible); and then a quotation mark.

Using [this example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002601903.htm) from the SAS documentation, something like this should work:

```
data test;
   set _your_data_set;
   retain re;
   if _N_ = 1 then re = prxparse('/\.(.*?)\"/');
   if prxmatch(re, var) then result = prxposn(re, 1, var);
run;
```

(This assumes your data is in a variable called `var`.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the PRX functions, something like the following might suffice:

```
text=scan(scan(line,2,"."),1,'"');
```

This assumes the text is stored in a variable called line.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me

```
SUBSTR(
t1.field, 
index(t1.field,'.')+1,
(index(t1.field,'"')-index(t1.field,'.')-1)
)
```

Comment: Hello @Moacyr and welcome to SO :) You can format your code with backticks ` ` for `better readability`. Saludos !